# Nav bar disappears when navigating to a specific view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I have a `UINavigationController` and I push and pop views, but in some views, I want to go to specific view from the stack so I use this code. It works but the nav bar disappears.

```
for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
        if controller.isKind(of: HomeViewController.self) {
        self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
            break
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HomeViewController you could try the following:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
   }
```

Comment: Sure, this function "setNavigationBarHidden" does what it's name implies, it lets you decide whether you want to hide or show your nav bar. As for why your nav bar disappeared when you popped to the HomeVC I should check your code to answer. Most common (at least in my projects) is that the preceding VC in the view hierarchy had it's nav bar hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically show the Navigation Bar as mentioned in Idem's comment, or if you are using XCode interface builder you may also want to ensure that the Status Bar is properly defined for each View in the Simulated Metrics area of the properties for the View - this works for non-Storyboard layouts.
[Simulated Metrics Section of properties in XCode Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zljb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to answer proposed by @ldem

However you can also try presenting the view rather than popping

so change

```
self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

to

```
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```